# K-finiteness of unitary representations of Poincaré-like groups?

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, mp.mathematical-physics

$\DeclareMathOperator\SO{SO}\DeclareMathOperator\ISO{ISO}$I'd like to know if there are any papers that study the following problems:

- Determine when decomposing the unitary irreps of $\ISO(d,1)$ into those of $\SO(d)$, whether the multiplicities are finite or not.
- The same problem for $\SO(p)\times \SO(q)\to \ISO(p,q)$.
- The Poincaré-like groups $\ISO(p,q)$ can be treated as the Inonu-Wigner contractions of the semisimple ones $\SO(p+1,q)$ (the physics picture is for example to take flat limit of symmetric spaces of $\SO(p+1,q)$).
  The $K$-contents of quasisimple irreps are better understood than those of $\ISO(p,q)$, and it's easy to further decompose $\SO(p+1)$ into $\SO(p)$. Is it possible to understand the Inonu-Wigner contraction at the level of $K$-content?

For the simplest case $\ISO(2,1)$, I know the answer of question 1 is affirmative by explicit calculations, and partially know the results of question 3.

Any suggestions and related references are appreciated!

Comment: What does ISO($p,q$) denote? (I know O($p,q$) and SO($p,q$))

Comment: @YCor It's similar to the Poincare group, the semidirect product of $SO(p,q)$ on $\mathbb{R}^{p+q}$. "I" means inhomogeneous. The maximal compact subgroup is the same as $SO(p,q)$, hence $SO(p)\times SO(q)$.

Comment: Thank you. Of course I know this group but I was not familiar with the notation.